# python postgresql db - изменить кодировку

Tags: python, postgresql

Помогите правильно считать данные из таблицы.

Пример программы

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbn, user=dbuser, password=dbpas, host=dbhost)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(“SELECT * FROM list_oid”)
row = cursor.fetchone()
for row in cursor:
   print(row.decode('utf8'))
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Стандартная программа для чтения таблиц.
Второй вариант без цикла
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbn, user=dbuser, password=dbpas, host=dbhost)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(“SELECT * FROM list_oid”)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        print(row.decode('utf8'))

Получаю ошибку

```
print(row.decode('utf8'))
AttributeError: ‘tuple’ object has no attribute ‘decode’
без декодера получаю = d0\xb4\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9
```

итд

А должно быть нормальный русский текст. Кодировка стоит по умолчания print conn.encoding = ‘utf8’.
Понимаю что контейнер Но надо как то его в нормальный вид вывести 
Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, в переменной `row` содержится кортеж, а не строка. Во-вторых, вам не нужен цикл, если вы выбираете одну строку.